# Chrome Extension Isn't executing?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "Name",
  "version": "0.1",
  "manifest_version" : 2,
  "description": "Does Stuff",
  "background" : {
    "scripts" : ["background.js"]
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon16.png"
   },

  "permissions": ["activeTab"]
}
```

background.js:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
   chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "script.js"});
});
```

script.js:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("[id^='MTG_INSTR$']") ).forEach( el => 
{
  el.textContent = "Test";
});
```

I can pop my script.js code into the console when I'm the page I intend to run the extension, and on the console there it works.

When I load my extension and click it on the page, it doesn't work. What gives?

Comment: Did it shows any errors in console ?

Comment: After testing out this code, I was not able to access script.js file, so first thing I had to do is to add it in `scripts` section like this.

`"scripts" : ["background.js", "script.js"]`

There are some permission errors later, but I think this is a good start.